# RHEL/CentOS Now to add nftable rules to firewalld on system boot?

Tags: firewalld, nftables

I am using firewalld on RHEL 8, and need to add a few nftable rules as well.

(The nftable rules are based on the answer to [CentOS 8 as NAT router with nft and firewalld - how to get it to pass TFTP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1042106/centos-8-as-nat-router-with-nft-and-firewalld-how-to-get-it-to-pass-tftp/1042370#1042370))

In a running firewall, this works well with the nft -f  command.

However, this gets lost on a reboot.

The [RedHat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/getting-started-with-nftables_configuring-and-managing-networking) (behind paywall) suggests using the nftables.service service to load rules on reboot, but this does not work in conjunction with firewalld. The two services are listed as conflicting, and even if they weren't, firewalld would likely flush the nftable rules.

Is there another way to get the nftable rules to load on restart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *firewalld* utility, when using the *nftables* backend, [will not flush tables that don't belong to it](https://firewalld.org/2018/07/nftables-backend#only-flush-firewallds-rules):

> Only flush firewalld’s rules
>
> Since nftables allows namespaces (via tables) **firewalld no longer does
> a complete flush of firewall rules**. It will only flush rules in the
> *firewalld* table. This avoids scenarios where custom user rules or
> rules installed by other tools are unexpectedly wiped out when
> firewalld was restarted or reloaded.

The same has just to be done when managing other tables.

Actually in the previous answer, it's already done: the *nftables* rules idempotently deletes *only* their own table: `handletftp`.

Sadly, that's not the case for `nftables.service` for the *stop* action:

> ```
> ExecStop=/sbin/nft flush ruleset
> ```

One must just ensure that the stop part of the systemd service doesn't directly flush all rules while still doing the job. This job will be delegated into dedicated *nftables* rules for the *stop* action.

So here's a practical method: duplicate (eg: `systemctl cat nftables.services`) and alter `nftables.service` into an instantiated version `local-idempotent-nft@.service` to be put in `/etc/systemd/system/local-idempotent-nft@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Idempotent nftables rules for %I
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
ExecStart=/sbin/nft -f /etc/nftables/idempotent/%I.nft
# As the rules are idempotent, ExecReload is same as ExecStart
ExecReload=/sbin/nft -f /etc/nftables/idempotent/%I.nft
# The stop rules should only have the first boilerplate parts
ExecStop=/sbin/nft -f /etc/nftables/idempotent/stop-%I.nft
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Create the dedicated configuration directory used above:

```
mkdir -p /etc/nftables/idempotent
```

Place rules that for each table defined, always start like this, so loading the rules is independent of other tables and [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) (example with tables `ip foo` and `bridge bar`):

```
table ip foo
delete table ip foo

table bridge bar
delete table bridge bar

table ip foo {
    ...
}

table bridge bar {
    ....
}
```

or just use one table per file. The `flush ruleset` statement is prohibited since it's global.

The reason a table is created, deleted and recreated is to get the result idempotent: while deleting a non-existing table is an error and would atomically make the whole loading fail, declaring an existing table without defining it (by adding an empty table) never fails and does nothing *except creating it empty* if it didn't exist before. In both cases (didn't exist at boot, exists at reload) *delete* can now work, leaving the place to really define the table right after. All this is happening in the same transaction and is still atomic: no packet will ever be evaluated with a missing *ip foo* table if it existed before during this.

Prepare a *stop* version of above that will only delete (here the empty declarations aren't strictly needed and could be removed if there was only one table, but should be kept if there's more than one table: failure is for the whole transaction):

```
table ip foo
delete table ip foo

table bridge bar
delete table bridge bar
```

and put everything in their location:

```
/etc/nftables/idempotent/foobar.nft
/etc/nftables/idempotent/stop-foobar.nft
```

This can now be activated with:

```
systemctl enable --now local-idempotent-nft@foobar
```

Example from previous OP's question:

in `/etc/nftables/idempotent/handletftp.nft`:

```
table ip handletftp
delete table ip handletftp

table ip handletftp {
    ct helper helper-tftp {
        type "tftp" protocol udp
    }

    chain sethelper {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
        ip saddr 192.168.1.0/24 ip daddr 10.0.10.10 udp dport 69 ct helper set "helper-tftp"
    }
}
```

In `/etc/nftables/idempotent/stop-handletftp.nft`

```
table ip handletftp
delete table ip handletftp
```

Enabling and starting it:

```
systemctl enable --now local-idempotent-nft@handletftp
```

Stopping it:

```
systemctl stop local-idempotent-nft@handletftp
```

which will leave *firewalld*'s rules in place. Likewise, stopping or restarting *firewalld* will leave these rules in place.

There are probably improvements to do:

- *nftables* has an *include* statement which could be used somehow to avoid duplication of boilerplate.
- the specific example about TFTP relies on the loading of `nf_nat_tftp` which won't be done automatically (contrary to `nf_conntrack_tftp` which is automatically loaded from reference in the rules or contrary to *firewalld* which would load `nf_nat_tftp` explicitly). So related but non-strictly *nftables* configurations should be kept in mind (this one setting could simply be put in `/etc/modules-load.d/`).

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much! I love the idea of using a parameterized service to make this more generic.

Comment: It appears that firewalld with nftables backend, contrary to what the blog tells, will still flush iptables rules too. (see https://serverfault.com/questions/1079695/iptables-flushed-on-firewalld-reload )