# DNSMASQ-TFTP failed sending file for PXE boot

Tags: redhat, dhcp, pxe-boot, udp, tftp

2 month ago my PXE installation worked perfectly, now it can't send the file grubx64.efi to begin the PXE installation.

```
juil. 08 08:03:05 install-server.my.domain dnsmasq[5913]: started, version 2.79 DNS disabled
juil. 08 08:03:05 install-server.my.domain dnsmasq[5913]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-i18n IDN2 DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
juil. 08 08:03:05 install-server.my.domain dnsmasq-dhcp[5913]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.0.2 -- 192.168.0.50, lease time 2m
juil. 08 08:03:05 install-server.my.domain dnsmasq-tftp[5913]: TFTP root is /tftpboot
juil. 08 08:04:20 install-server.my.domain dnsmasq-dhcp[5913]: DHCPDISCOVER(eth0) aa:bb:cc:11:22:33
juil. 08 08:04:20 install-server.my.domain dnsmasq-dhcp[5913]: DHCPOFFER(eth0) 192.168.0.2 aa:bb:cc:11:22:33
juil. 08 08:04:24 install-server.my.domain dnsmasq-dhcp[5913]: DHCPREQUEST(eth0) 192.168.0.2 aa:bb:cc:11:22:33
juil. 08 08:04:24 install-server.my.domain dnsmasq-dhcp[5913]: DHCPACK(eth0) 192.168.0.2 aa:bb:cc:11:22:33
juil. 08 08:04:25 install-server.my.domain dnsmasq-dhcp[5913]: PXE(eth0) 192.168.0.2 aa:bb:cc:11:22:33 grubx64.efi
juil. 08 08:06:40 install-server.my.domain dnsmasq-tftp[5913]: failed sending /tftpboot/grubx64.efi to 192.168.0.2
juil. 08 08:06:44 install-server.my.domain dnsmasq-tftp[5913]: failed sending /tftpboot/grubx64.efi to 192.168.0.2
juil. 08 08:06:48 install-server.my.domain dnsmasq-tftp[5913]: failed sending /tftpboot/grubx64.efi to 192.168.0.2
```

As you can see, the host makes a DHCP requests and get an IP based on it's mask as configured in /etc/dnsmas.d/pxe.conf

```
interface=eth0
#bind-interfaces
domain=my.domain
# DHCP range-leases
dhcp-range=eth0,192.168.0.2,192.168.0.50,255.255.255.0,2m
#DHCP-HOST
dhcp-host=aa:bb:cc:11:22:33,192.168.0.2
# PXE
dhcp-boot=pxlinux.0,install-server.my.domain,192.168.1.185
dhcp-boot=grubx64.efi,install-server.my.domain,192.168.1.185
# Gateway
dhcp-option=3,192.168.0.254
# Broadcast Address
dhcp-option=28,10.0.0.255
# NTP Server
dhcp-option=42,0.0.0.0

pxe-prompt="Press F8 for menu.", 60
pxe-service=X86-64_EFI, "UEFI RHEL8/Centos8 from server 192.168.1.185", grubx64.efi
pxe-service=X86-64_EFI, "LEGACY RHEL8/Centos8 from server 192.168.1.185", pxelinux
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/tftpboot
```

The install server is in another network but I have a DHCP forward in a physical firewall on the network.
Here is the logs of a tcpdump I made checking for the host ip (so after the DHCP request).

```
08:04:25.408381 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22212, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 384)
    client-host.my.domain.pxe > install-server.my.domain.pxe: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 356
08:04:25.408520 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 51864, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 338)
    install-server.my.domain.pxe > client-host.my.domain.pxe: [bad udp cksum 0x3239 -> 0x8627!] UDP, length 310
08:04:26.212512 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22213, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 82)
    client-host.my.domain.msmq > install-server.my.domain.tftp: [udp sum ok]  54 RRQ "grubx64.efi" octet tsize 0 blksize 1468 windowsize 4
08:04:26.212631 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 52643, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.37879 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x1642!] UDP, length 16
08:04:26.213928 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22214, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 52643, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 6cec (->7c34)!)
    install-server.my.domain.37879 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:28.215103 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 53840, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.37879 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x1642!] UDP, length 16
08:04:28.216469 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22215, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 53840, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 683f (->7787)!)
    install-server.my.domain.37879 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:30.247594 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22216, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 82)
    client-host.my.domain.msmq > install-server.my.domain.tftp: [udp sum ok]  54 RRQ "grubx64.efi" octet tsize 0 blksize 1468 windowsize 4
08:04:30.247715 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 55676, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.63703 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xb161!] UDP, length 16
08:04:30.249021 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22217, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 55676, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 6113 (->705b)!)
    install-server.my.domain.63703 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:31.248883 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56468, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.37879 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x1642!] UDP, length 16
08:04:31.250047 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22218, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56468, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 5dfb (->6d43)!)
    install-server.my.domain.37879 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:32.250069 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57252, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.63703 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xb161!] UDP, length 16
08:04:32.251593 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22219, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57252, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 5aeb (->6a33)!)
    install-server.my.domain.63703 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:34.288725 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22220, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 82)
    client-host.my.domain.msmq > install-server.my.domain.tftp: [udp sum ok]  54 RRQ "grubx64.efi" octet tsize 0 blksize 1468 windowsize 4
08:04:34.288893 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57487, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.52881 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xdba7!] UDP, length 16
08:04:34.290134 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22221, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57487, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 5a00 (->6948)!)
    install-server.my.domain.52881 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:35.040026 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57726, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.63703 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xb161!] UDP, length 16
08:04:35.041168 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22222, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57726, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 5911 (->6859)!)
    install-server.my.domain.63703 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:36.041381 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58255, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.52881 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xdba7!] UDP, length 16
08:04:36.041390 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58256, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.37879 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x1642!] UDP, length 16
08:04:36.042695 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22223, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58255, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 5700 (->6648)!)
    install-server.my.domain.52881 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:36.042701 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22224, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58256, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 56ff (->6647)!)
    install-server.my.domain.37879 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:38.325832 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22225, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 82)
    client-host.my.domain.msmq > install-server.my.domain.tftp: [udp sum ok]  54 RRQ "grubx64.efi" octet tsize 0 blksize 1468 windowsize 4
08:04:38.325937 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59359, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.65269 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xab43!] UDP, length 16
08:04:38.327234 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22226, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59359, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 52b0 (->61f8)!)
    install-server.my.domain.65269 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:39.076826 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59949, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.52881 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xdba7!] UDP, length 16
08:04:39.078267 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22227, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59949, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 5062 (->5faa)!)
    install-server.my.domain.52881 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:40.078109 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 60833, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.65269 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xab43!] UDP, length 16
08:04:40.078128 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 60834, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.63703 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xb161!] UDP, length 16
08:04:40.079297 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22228, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 60834, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 4ced (->5c35)!)
    install-server.my.domain.63703 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:40.079306 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22229, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 60833, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 4cee (->5c36)!)
    install-server.my.domain.65269 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:42.362965 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22230, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 82)
    client-host.my.domain.msmq > install-server.my.domain.tftp: [udp sum ok]  54 RRQ "grubx64.efi" octet tsize 0 blksize 1468 windowsize 4
08:04:42.363200 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62336, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.43294 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x011b!] UDP, length 16
08:04:42.364362 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22231, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62336, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 470f (->5657)!)
    install-server.my.domain.43294 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:43.114150 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62456, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.65269 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xab43!] UDP, length 16
08:04:43.115391 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22232, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62456, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 4697 (->55df)!)
    install-server.my.domain.65269 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:44.115353 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63169, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.43294 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x011b!] UDP, length 16
08:04:44.115374 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63170, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.52881 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xdba7!] UDP, length 16
08:04:44.116952 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22233, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63169, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 43ce (->5316)!)
    install-server.my.domain.43294 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:44.116960 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22234, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63170, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 43cd (->5315)!)
    install-server.my.domain.52881 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:45.116587 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63574, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.37879 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x1642!] UDP, length 16
08:04:45.118479 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22235, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63574, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 4239 (->5181)!)
    install-server.my.domain.37879 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:46.403078 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22236, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 82)
    client-host.my.domain.msmq > install-server.my.domain.tftp: [udp sum ok]  54 RRQ "grubx64.efi" octet tsize 0 blksize 1468 windowsize 4
08:04:46.403202 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63654, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.45854 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xf71a!] UDP, length 16
08:04:46.404463 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22237, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63654, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 41e9 (->5131)!)
    install-server.my.domain.45854 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:47.154159 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 64313, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.43294 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x011b!] UDP, length 16
08:04:47.155554 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22238, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 64313, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 3f56 (->4e9e)!)
    install-server.my.domain.43294 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:48.155383 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 64897, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.45854 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xf71a!] UDP, length 16
08:04:48.155402 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 64898, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.65269 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xab43!] UDP, length 16
08:04:48.156575 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22239, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 64897, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 3d0e (->4c56)!)
    install-server.my.domain.45854 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:48.156584 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22240, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 64898, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 3d0d (->4c55)!)
    install-server.my.domain.65269 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:49.156662 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 350, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.63703 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xb161!] UDP, length 16
08:04:49.158131 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22241, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 56)
    client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36
    IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 350, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44, bad cksum 3932 (->487a)!)
    install-server.my.domain.63703 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: UDP, length 16
08:04:51.159273 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 2296, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.45854 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xf71a!] UDP, length 16
08:04:52.160713 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 2710, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.43294 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x011b!] UDP, length 16
08:04:53.162031 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 3266, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.52881 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xdba7!] UDP, length 16
08:04:56.165878 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 4452, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.45854 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xf71a!] UDP, length 16
08:04:57.167255 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 4533, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.65269 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xab43!] UDP, length 16
08:05:01.172591 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8065, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.43294 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x011b!] UDP, length 16
08:05:02.173884 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 9037, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.37879 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x1642!] UDP, length 16
08:05:05.179113 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10580, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.45854 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xf71a!] UDP, length 16
08:05:06.180485 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 11167, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.63703 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xb161!] UDP, length 16
08:05:10.185410 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 13844, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.52881 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xdba7!] UDP, length 16
08:05:14.190443 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 14710, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.65269 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xab43!] UDP, length 16
08:05:18.195328 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 15745, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.43294 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x011b!] UDP, length 16
08:05:22.200379 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 18804, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.45854 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xf71a!] UDP, length 16
08:05:35.216476 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 27301, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.37879 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x1642!] UDP, length 16
08:05:39.221480 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 27378, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.63703 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xb161!] UDP, length 16
08:05:43.226525 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30252, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.52881 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xdba7!] UDP, length 16
08:05:47.231051 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31405, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.65269 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xab43!] UDP, length 16
08:05:51.235911 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 35187, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.43294 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0x011b!] UDP, length 16
08:05:55.241080 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 37681, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 44)
    install-server.my.domain.45854 > client-host.my.domain.msmq: [bad udp cksum 0x3113 -> 0xf71a!] UDP, length 16
```

If someone has an idea on where the problem might be ? I have looked in many places but don't seem to find something (Tried disabling software firewall on install-server, any -> any in physical firewall, disabled SELinux. So no problems on infrastructure as it is the same as when it worked).

One thing that changed for sure is DNSMASQ so it may have changed some of it's behaviours.

Somme more informations :

- Name/IPs are placeholders
- OS Redhat 8.6 : 4.18.0-372.13.1el8_6.x86_64
- dnsmasq version 2.79

update 23/11/2022
I installed tftp client on the same machine already installed and there is no problem to get the file

I deactivated tftp startup on dnsmasq and set up tftp-server in standalone. I get this new logs

```
nov. 23 08:48:48 install-server.my.domain in.tftpd[22012]: RRQ from ::ffff:192.168.0.2 filename grubx64.efi
nov. 23 08:48:48 install-server.my.domain in.tftpd[22012]: tftpd: read: Connection refused
```

Tried disabling all securities (selinux, logical and physical firewall) and still nothing

Didn't update bios of the client. It just broke after maybe dnsmasq/tftp-server update

Comment: `client-host.my.domain > install-server.my.domain: ICMP client-host.my.domain udp port msmq unreachable, length 36`  (5th packet) shows the error. Is TFTP done in the same LAN? Is it routed and/or NAT'ed with a firewall between? etc.

Comment: Didn't see it was told: routed. See this related Q/A where I made an answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/1042106/centos-8-as-nat-router-with-nft-and-firewalld-how-to-get-it-to-pass-tftp  (it might not be about NAT but if there's firewalld around it would still be relevant)

Comment: You should take capture in different places and see you capture the same (especially the ICMP errors). Then you should use wireshark to help see f there's a problem in the protocol. And of course if the "physical firewall" is involved, that's the first place to check.

Comment: I deactivated firewalld and still nothing so it shouldn't be the software firewall ? Same with physical firewall, I put any -> any between my install server subnetwork and host subnetwork. Overall, I didn't changed the network configuration and it broke. Only changes were pxe.conf and dnsmasq verion.

Comment: here are schematics showing the peculiarities of the tftp protocol with dynamic ports involved: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol#Details so you understand why "trivial ftp" is not trivial to firewall. If it worked before revert to the previous configuaration and see from which change it breaks.

Comment: I Know how TFTP works with selecting random ports for the transfer. I had this problem while configuring the physical firewall, in one way I limited the ports and the other opened all the ports. I wish I could go back to a version that works but our production is in another country and PXE is tested only while where there. I made this post because I don't understand what breaks the TFTP transfer. I will investigate further by sniffing with wireshark in the host subnetwork.